# When creating a Kafka stream with GQLAlchemy which arguments are required?

Tags: memgraphdb

I've taken a look at the documentation on [creating Kafka streams using GQLAlchemy](https://memgraph.com/docs/gqlalchemy/how-to-guides/streams/manage-kafka-streams#1-create-a-kafka-stream-in-memgraph), but I don't get which parameters are optional and which ones are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Required parameters are `name`, `topics` and `transform`. When you create `MemgraphKafkaStream` instance, you actually run `CREATE KAFKA STREAM` query, so it's best to refer to the [Memgraph docs](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/reference-guide/streams/#kafka-and-redpanda) for such questions. There you can see that other arguments are optional.